# Поясните работу конструкции if m:

Tags: python

```
>>> m = 'Non'

>>> if m == True:
    print('ok')
else:
    print('error')    
error
>>>
```

А вот если сделать вот так!

```
>>> if m:
     print('ok')
else:
    print('error')    
ok
>>>
```

Во второй сессии мы получаем `ОК`.

Почему так происходит? Я думал выражение `if m:` - это тоже самое что `if m== True`, если думать так, то и ответ должен быть один и тот же.

**Исправьте меня!**

Answer (score 11):

Когда Вы пишете `if m == True:`, Вы требуете явного совпадения, если же Вы пишете `if m:`, действуют следующие правила проверки истинности:

- любое число, не равное `0`, или непустой объект - истина;
- числа, равные `0`, пустые объекты и значение `None` - ложь.

Таким образом,

```
m == True  ==>  'Non' == True  ==>  False
```

но поскольку `m` - непустой объект, то он принимается за `True`.

Answer (score 0):

В питоне есть такое понятие как Falsy values, в которые входят

```
False, [], {}, list(), set(), None, 0 -
```

Так вот, при встрече с условным оператом:

```
a = []
if a:  ==> False
```

интерпретатор вызывает метод `__bool__`, если он не реализован, то вызывается метод `__len__`. получается из за того, что `len([]), len({})` равны нулю они и возвращают False.

А вообще интуитивно все правильно, то есть пустой массив должен быть False, поэтому думаю, что это фича.

кстати любой объект пользовательского класса (созданный программистом например) всегда будет истиной, если не определен метод `__bool__`, то проверка на истинность объекта вернет сам объект.